# Simple but difficult. How to force external libs functions run sequentially?

Tags: javascript, sequential

If we have two function in javascript, one **slow** and one **fast**. For example:

```
function slow() {
    setTimeout(function() {console.log("slow finished")}, 10000);
}

function fast() {
    console.log("fast");
}
```

And these functions don't have inside of them new structures like promisses (if we do not implement after).

How can we force these functions run in order? For example:

```
function run() {
    slow();
    fast();
}

run();
```

How can we force **fast** wait **slow** finishes?
I'm looking a solution that could work inside mobile application browsers, becase of a Apache Cordova project of mine.

Is there a way to do this?

An idea of mine is inject a callback function between the functions.
And this callback is called at the end of the **slow** function, calling the **fast** function.

An important thing is I can't (or would not) rewrite the code of the **slow** and **fast** functions,
because they will reside inside external libraries.

I'm looking for a solution to countorn this problem as an external observer and manager.

How can we do this?

**Edit**

He I was a trying to solve the problem merging the answers. No success yet.
I had changed **slow** but this is not really allowed. I have changed it to se what is happening with **a**. I couldn't get something interesting because **a** becomes undefined immediately and not after **slow** finishes...

```
  var a = "adsfadsfadsf";
  function slow() {
    setTimeout(function() {console.log("slow done"); console.log("a2", window.a);}, 3000);
  }

  function fast() {
    console.log("a3", window.a);
    console.log("fast done");
  }

  var newSlow = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      window.a = slow();
      console.log("a", a);
      resolve("Sucess");
    });
  };

  newSlow().then(function(resolve){fast();}, function(reject){console.log("error");});
```

I have tried with **resolve(slow());** no sucess too.

Comment: If you know how long it will take the slow one, you could put the fast one within a timeout with a higher time.

Comment: I have considered this possibility, but I would like a automatic method, that call the another function imediately after the slow one finishes. If I have a network problem or a slowness in the system this will not work properly.

Comment: does the slow() function return any value?

Comment: @SaumilSoni Yes and not. I prefer a solution that works for both, but if it returns something is possible I would like to know. Thx.

Comment: Well, if it returns something, you can wait for it to be assigned before calling the next one, something like:

    var return = slow();
    while (!return) {
          setTimeout(function() {console.log("waiting just a little")}, 100);
    }
    fast();

Comment: If the implementation of `slow` does not include even a `callback` function, I don't see how this could be implemented. Contrariwise, I can think of many things a function could do that could set up other functions, and either call them once, never, or once every 10 seconds for the rest of eternity. You at least need *some* kind of pattern to recognize, and/or cooperation from the method.

Answer (score 2):

That's a very interesting question. Well I can think of a way where if it is changing some global variable "g" to some value say "true". In that case if you can run them sequentially as,

```
<script>
var g = false;
var i;
function slow() {
setTimeout(function() {console.log("slow finished");g=true;}, 10000);
}

function fast() {
    console.log("fast");
}
    function run() {
    slow();
    i = setInterval(function(){check();},1000);
}
function check(){

    if(g){
        fast();
        clearInterval(i);
    }    
}
run();
</script>
```

[**As in this demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/saumil_sss/3k5uxt64/1/)

**UPDATE:** Something just struck me and I guess we might be able to add a callback function to `slow()` even if we can't access it directly.

If a function is called without parenthesis then the entire function as a content is returned as a string so we can edit that string by adding `fast()` to it registering that string as a function using `eval()`.

```
function run() {
    var myFun = slow+"";
    myFun = myFun.substring(0,myFun.length-1);
    alert(myFun);
    myFun += "fast();}";

    //to register the string "myFun" as a function
    eval(myFun);

    slow();
}
```

So basically our `slow()` function becomes,

```
function slow(){

    //function code

    //the appended function
    fast();

}
```

**NOTE:** This will not worked in the example given above where GarouDan has deliberately added setTimeout limit to recreate a scenario where the `slow()` function takes longer time than the `fast()` function. However, in a real-world scenario I'm sure this approach would definetly work.

Comment: That is how I would do it.

Comment: In fact is an interesting solution, and I tried to change it a little bit. But you needed to modify the slow function (to modify g, but this maybe cannot be done, because is a function that we do not control). I was thinking if we could clone the function, or start g with a hash = "asdfasdfadsfadsf" and set this value with the return of slow (undefined or not could help). But I cant create a working example with these ideas...

Comment: @GarouDan check out my updated answer, I think this might help you.

Comment: @GarouDan do tell if it works for you, I'm very curious about it's usage.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Promise](https://www.promisejs.org/patterns/) pattern.

Promises are tailor made for situations where various parts of code may run slow or fast or complete in unknowable amounts of time (or not complete at all), while still giving you execution control.

My personal favorite library that implements the Promise pattern is [RSVP](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js/).

Here is some pseudocode to give you the idea. Run an operation that may take a long time, then run one only when the first has either completed, or handle it's failure.

```
function doFoo() {

    var promise = new RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    // do some long-running operation, like retrieve
    // data from a slow site...

    if (data.Status && data.Status === 200) {
        resolve(data);
    } else {
        reject(data.Error)
        }

    });
    return promise;
}

function doBar() {
    var promise = new RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        // do some fast operation, like count to 10
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            console.log(i);
        }

        resolve("");
    });
    return promise;
}
```

Now you can call:

```
function inOrder() {
    doFoo().then(function(success) {
        doBar();
    }).catch (function(failure) {
        console.log("oops! " + failure);
    }
    });
}
```

This runs doFoo, and ONLY runs doBar after doFoo has completed successfully. Note that you could also run doBar even if doFoo has failed.

Comment: I'm trying put this to work with the two functions at the question. In fact use Promises is a very interesting thing, but can we create a working example (without rewrite the functions, just manage in a external way) with this Promise pattern? I'm trying here but I couldn't do it yet.